# Как узнать внешний ip адрес на android?

Tags: android

С помощью данного кода я определяю локальный ip адрес.
Что нужно добавить что бы ещё и внешний айпи узнать? 
Было бы не плохо если кто-то бы показал наглядно

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //айпи адрес локальный
    varTxtIp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.local_ip);


    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo WifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = WifiInfo.getIpAddress();

    String macAddress = WifiInfo.getMacAddress();
    String bssid = WifiInfo.getBSSID();
    int rssi = WifiInfo.getRssi();
    int linkSpeed = WifiInfo.getLinkSpeed();
    String ssid = WifiInfo.getSSID();
    int networkid = WifiInfo.getNetworkId();
    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
    String info = "Локальный IP: " + ipAddress;
    varTxtIp.setText(info);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант https://api.ipify.org?format=json
Получите свой IP - {"ip":"55.100.128.128"}

Comment: можете пожалуйста показать пример как использовать данные с этого сайта. Просто я перерыл куча сайтов про json но так и не нашел нужного примера реализации этого.

Answer (score 0):

Без внешнего сервера вы внешний IP достоверно не узнаете. В качестве такого сервиса могут выступать серверы STUN, dDNS и подобные.